# Unable to combine Date Criteria in Query Function in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, import, google-sheets-formula

I am using query and importrange function to collect data from another Google sheet, i have already filtered a column, but now i have to filter FROM the main sheet on a date column (ABOVE MAY 2022) in the Query function. this is my actual function that i have tried but it doesnt works. I would appreciate some help with this.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("2WdjuvMkDmxjFT6IgQmXeQ8xn1fs5T-JkSVar86P7KdQ";"A:D");"Select Col1, Col3, Col4 Where Col3 contains 'Santa Cruz' and where Col1 = date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are allowed to use `where` only once:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("2WdjuvMkDmxjFT6IgQmXeQ8xn1fs5T-JkSVar86P7KdQ"; "A:D");
 "select Col1,Col3,Col4 
  where Col3 contains 'Santa Cruz' 
    and Col1 = date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think the syntax must be with hours, minutes, and seconds. In the main sheet the syntax of the datetime is: ex. 3/01/2020 16:32:30, i dont know how the query coding would be because of that, the date must be greather that the year 2021. any help please?                                                                                             Coding: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("2WdjuvMkDmxjFT6IgQmXeQ8xn1fs5T-JkSVar86P7KdQ";"A:D");"Select Col1, Col3, Col4 Where Col3 contains 'Santa Cruz' and Col1 = date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&")")""

Comment: @MariaFernandaFerreiraAlfaro can you share a copy of your sheet?